# How do I get Wix to automatically uninstall an older build of an installer?

Tags: installation, wix

I used the following [links advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500703/how-to-get-wix-to-update-a-previously-installed-version-of-a-program), but it did not seem to resolve my issue. I wish to it to automatically remove any older builds (not just major version numbers). Whenever I use that code, it complains that an existing install is there and that I need to remove it manually beforehand. I wish to automate this process. If someone could point me into the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also, changing the product code in the newer installers only seems to create another install, leaving the older installer behind.

Comment: It seems to answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114165/how-to-implement-wix-installer-upgrade