# Prevent downgrading from a bundle

Tags: wix

before I would just use 1 wxs project file to install my app. This would uninstall all previous versions before installing.

Now I have added a bundle and it no longer works.  If I change the setup file like adding another file or registry setting and attempt install it will create another entry in my program and features list.

How can i get the same action/behavior from a bundle?

This snippet is what is inside my Product wxs file:

```
<MajorUpgrade 
  AllowDowngrades="no"
  AllowSameVersionUpgrades="no"
  IgnoreRemoveFailure="no"
  DowngradeErrorMessage="loc.NewerVersionInstalled"
  Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"/>

<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action='PreventDowngrading' After='FindRelatedProducts'>NEWPRODUCTFOUND</Custom>
</InstallUISequence>

<CustomAction Id='PreventDowngrading' Error='Newer version already installed' />
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" />


<UI>
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
  <Publish 
    Dialog="ExitDialog"
    Control="Finish"
    Event="DoAction"
    Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed
  </Publish>
</UI>
```

thanks

Comment: Is your version string 3 fields or 4?  Be aware that Windows Installer only inspects the first 3 fields in your version string to determine if a package with the same `UpgradeCode` is a different version. Take a look at this wix document: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/updates/major_upgrade.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get wix to update a previously installed version of a program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500703/how-to-get-wix-to-update-a-previously-installed-version-of-a-program)

Comment: @khargoosh thanks for that link