# wix 3 installer: Unresolved bind-time variable !(bind.fileVersion.Name.exe)

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3, wix3.8

I'm trying to use the binding "bind.fileVersion" from Wix3. (ie: 3.11.1)

For some me reason, I get the following error message:

**Unresolved bind-time variable !(bind.fileVersion.TestWix3.exe).**

My goal is to fill the 'Product Id' line. Especially the Version="$(var.VERSION)" information.

Here's the content of my "Product.wxs" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?define LongName = "Test wix 3" ?>    
<?define Manufacturer = "Test" ?>
<?define ProductUpgradeCode = "5fc3e435-fad3-4c1d-997f-3483beffe0a4" ?>

<?define MAINEXE=$(var.TestWix3.TargetFileName)?>
<?define VERSION="!(bind.fileVersion.$(var.MAINEXE))"?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <Product Id="*" Name="$(var.LongName)" Language="1036" Codepage="1252" Version="$(var.VERSION)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Wix3Installer" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Wix3Installer" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
            <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
                <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
            <!-- </Component> -->     
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Here is the screenshot of my solution in VS2017 Community.
[image]

Here is the error:
[image]

Any idea why the binding of (bind.fileVersion) does not work ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The FileId part of the bind variable is representing the `<File Id="...">` Id. ie:

```
!(bind.fileVersion.TestWix3.exe)

...

<Component Id="MainProduct">
    <File Id="TestWix3.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.TestWix3.TargetPath)"/>
    ... other stuff maybe ...
</Component>
```

Currently your component and file definitions are `TODO` so you can't use this type of bind variable yet.

Comment: thanks. It solved the problem. I was not aware that I needed the File Id.

Comment: I defined the File Id, the error is still present. would be any other cause?

Comment: @XtianGIS if your component is defined in a fragment make sure that fragment is brought into the main product with a ComponentRef or ComponentGroupRef or FeatureRef depending on the structure of your install. You can also try making a small test install that includes everything in one file to see if you can get it working that way. Sometimes you can get in a state where your intermediate files aren't rebuilt but need to be so also try a clean and build. If none of that works probably make your own question on SO

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `!(bind.fileVersion.FileId)` -- note the lowercase `f`.

Comment: thanks but it did not fix the issue. Still the same issue with lower case f.

Answer (score 0):

Your define ?define MAINEXE=$(var.TestWix3.TargetFileName)?
translates to:
create a variable with Name MAINEXE and set it to the value of another variable.

There is no variable defined TestWix3.TargetFileName
Your second define created a variable with Name VERSION and uses the undefined MAINEXE

using the defines like this instead 
?define MAINEXE=sample.exe? 
?define VERSION="!(bind.fileVersion.$(var.MAINEXE))"?
compiles no problem

I ommitted the <&lt >&gt before and after ?

Comment: I tried with my exe name (TestWix3.exe). It did not work . (same error)

Comment: The correct solution seems to be the one given by Brian Sutherland

Answer (score 0):

In our case (C++ program), this bind.FileVersion error message apparently was fixed by adding Win32 rc VERSIONINFO resources that were actually missing in the relevant library project (I'd think that WiX requires proper version declaration of a binary to e.g. make its installation/upgrade decisions etc.).